# Akka become() and getSender() incompatible

Tags: java, concurrency, actor, akka

I have a question related to Akka 2.0.1 in the Java API. I have the following situation:

Actor A:
Receives a request from the UI. It will then do the following.

1. Wait for message from UI
2. Send msg to Actor B, to retrieve data
3. Become an actor which is handling the answer from actor B, when it has been retrieved.

Actor B:

1. Wait for message from Actor A.
2. Retrieves data
3. Calls `getSender().tell(xxx)`;

This doesn't work, and the Actor A will not received the answer. If however Actor B is using the global actorRef to Actor A in the system, in my case `zzz.eventCaller.tell(xxx)` it will however work.

Is is me who have missed some basic stuff, or is this expected behavior or a bug?

Comment: I'm so bad at guessing what peoples code looks like...

Comment: I will add example if I ever get problems understanding Akka again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't provide the actual code, you sort of left me to guess what your problem might be.
The Akka Java API has no way of tracking senders unless you provide them:

```
recipient.tell(message, getSelf());
```

I *hope* that helps.

Comment: You are right on the spot. As a sidenote I would like to mention I would prefer Scala, but that is not an option at my work for now:)